# JSX element type 'Header' does not have any construct or call signatures.ts(2604). Can someone help me fix this?

Tags: reactjs, .net, typescript, semantic-ui, tsx

I'm using the Header comp from Semantic-ui like this, and I'm having this error for some components, not only Header. All of the components are imported but some of them are not working.

```
    import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
    import logo from './logo.svg';
    import './App.css';
    import axios from 'axios';
    import { Header, HeaderContent, List, ListList } from 'semantic-ui-react';
    
    
    function App() {
    const [activities, setActivities]=useState([]);
    
    useEffect(()=>{
      axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/Activites').then(response =>{
        console.log(response);
        setActivities(response.data);
      })
    },[])
    
      return (
        <div>
          <HeaderContent as='h2' icon='users' content='Reactivites' ></HeaderContent>
            <ListList>
              {activities.map((activity: any)=>(
                <List.Item key={activity.id}>
                  {activity.title}
                </List.Item>
              ))}
            </ListList>
         
        </div>
      );
    }

export default App;
```

I am using typescript on my react project and semantic-ui for styling

My package.json looks like this, and if its needed to change version of some dependencies give me suggestions on the comments

```
    {
  "name": "client-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.1.1",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.4.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.31",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.4.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "postinstall": "semantic-ui-css-patch"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I know 100% that the error its from the semantic-ui and I would appreciate so much for some help and thank you in forward

I'm new to TypeScript and its my first time using semantic-ui